# Is styrene more or less reactive than benzene towards electrophiles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Is styrene more activated or more deactivated than benzene towards electrophilic aromatic substitution? The C=C double bond doesn't seem to have any particular electron-withdrawing or -donating properties, so I'm not sure what to make of it.

Comment: I guess for many agents the double bond is likely to be attacked first.

Answer (score 1):

Styrene (vinylbenzene) undergoes electrophilic aromatic substitution much faster than benzene. Although the vinyl group seems to be withdrawing, it offers +M effect in the carbocation intermediate. Resonance forms of the intermediates to explain these results. and the products are found to be primarily ortho- and para-substituted styrenes. The products are found to be primarily ortho- and para-substituted styrenes.

Comment: Do you have a reference to or example of EAS where the ring reacts rather than the double bond?